# Return multiple different fields as list item in listbox ms-access 2013 VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I have a listbox called "lbItems" which is set to the RowSource property of "Table/query". I have an VBA statement which runs a query that selects "lineItem" from a table and this populates the listbox with the lineItems as seen below:

```
Me.lbItems.RowSource = "SELECT lineItem FROM Table1"
```

[image]

This doesn't give me any information about the lineItems however, that is found in the field "description". I want to use an VBA statement which runs an SQL query like this:

```
Me.lbItems.RowSource = "SELECT lineItem, Description FROM Table1"
```

I would like the above statement to populate my listbox with the lineItem, and right beside it, the description with a pipe "|" character in between.

This is the problem though. If you choose a different RowSource for the listbox, then you are able to concatenate strings and put whatever you would like as a list item which is what I want to do. But, with RowSource set to table/query, I can only use queries to set the list items.

Question 1: Is there any way to mix both of the above methods together? So to combine SQL statements and my own operations to populate the listbox?

Question 2: If there isn't a way to do what was asked in Question 1, can I select more than 1 field with my SQL statement and set BOTH of those fields to the list item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, you just need to configure the listbox for this. Under the Property Sheet in the Access form for the listbox change the following:

- Change the "Column Count" to 2
- Set "Column Widths" to 1";2"
- Make sure "Bound Column" is 1

Comment: All I had to do was change the column widths from 0";2" to 1":2" and it gave me what I wanted. Other than that perfect!